# I have a few questions About the matrix and algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Iterative deblurring algorithm

Note that the size of the linear system (number of equations and unknowns) corresponding to the image blurring process is proportional to the number of pixels in the image. Therefore, even for a meager 100 x 100 image we need to solve a system with 10000 equations and unknowns to deblur the image. Therefore, we will attempt to utilize a simple approximate, iterative approach - in the same spirit as the power method for eigenvalue/eigenvector computation. Given a strictly diagonally dominant n x n matrix A and a right hand side $ b \in \mathbf{R^n}$ (this will correspond to a blurred image in our case), we will construct a sequence of approximate solutions $x^k$ , k = 0, 1, 2, ... to the system Ax = b as follows.

> 1. Select an arbitrary $x^0 \in  \mathbf{R^n} $
> 2. for k = 0,1,2...do
> 3. for i = 1,2..n do
> 4. Solve equation i independtly from all other equations:  $$x_i^{k+1} = A_{ii}^{-1}(b_i-\sum_{j\ne i} A_{ij} x_j^k$$
> 5. end for
> 6. if  $  \| x^{k+1} -x^k\|  $ is small enough then
> 7. Stop, $x^{k+1}$ is an approximate solution
> 8. End if
> 9. End for

One can show that this algorithm, known as the Jacobi iteration, converges for strictly diagonally dominant matrices to the solution of the linear system Ax = b from an arbitrary initial guess $x^ (0)$.

Question 3.

3.1 Assume that at some iteration of the algorithm above we have $x^{k+1}=x^k$ as excat eqaulity. Show that $Ax^{k+1}$ is the solution to our system of linear equations. This provids some motivation for the stopping criterion in the algorithm

3.2 Show that the update from $x^k $ to $x^{k+1}$ (lines 3-5 in the algorithm above) can be equal implemented as follows
$r^k=b-Ax^k$
for i = 1,2,..n do
$x_i^{k+1}+ A_{ii}^{-1} r_i^k= $

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Pictures are difficult for many users of this site to access. A good start might be Googling "Jacobi iteration" or "Jacobi method." When a buzzword like that is buried in the middle of a problem it is a sign that there is probably a lot written about it elsewhere

Comment: The proof for question 3.1 follows easily from the statement in question 3.2, so I'd do 3.2 first.

Comment: Both problems just use the definition of matrix multiplication.  I think you must not be  comfortable with the notation yet.  If $y = Ax$, then row $i$ of $y$ is $y_i=\sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}x_j$.